# evaluation of a regular expression /^\s*(\*|[\w\-]+)(?:\b|$)?/i

Tags: regex

I need some help in evaluating a regular expression in some code.I am trying to evaluate the regular expression

```
/^\s*(\*|[\w\-]+)(?:\b|$)?/i
```

I think I figured the following:

`^` - Beginning of character

`\s*` - zero or more occurrences of white space

`(\*|[\w\-]+)` - I understand the `\w` standards for word but I am not sure what `\*` and the or `|` is evaluating to and the `+` specifies one more more occurrence of the preceding pattern.

`(?:\b|$)?` - I need help in understanding this and the expression as a whole.

`i` - Ignore case

Can some help me understand what `(?:\b|$)?` is evaluating for and the expression as whole? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/                # Start regex delimiter.
^                # Anchor to start of string.
\s*              # Match 0 or more whitespace (\s) characters.
(\*|[\w\-]+)     # Alternation between a literal `*` and one or more word
                 # characters (\w) or a dash (needlessly escaped). Store in
                 # capturing group 1.
(?:\b|$)?        # Create a non capturing alternation between a word boundary
                 # or the end of the string. This entire alternation is 
                 # optional.
/                # End regex delimiter.
i                # Make the regex case insensitive. Needless here as there is 
                 # no literal alphabetical characters used.
```

Comment: It says `\*`, not `*`, so it's Alternation between '*' (a literal star) and whatever you said.

Comment: @dominikh Don't know how the \ was dropped in my copy paste. I'll fix it :)

Comment: It wasn't displayed because the regexp in the original post wasn't enclosed in `` and `\*` was escaping the `*` bold formatting :)

Comment: @dominikh Foiled by my own question editing. It should be good now :)